# Check whether a DataFrame or ndrray contains digits

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

It is few hours I am stuck with this:
I have a DataFrame containing a list of email addresses, from those email addresses I want to check whether in the mail is contained or not a number I.E. `roberto123@example.com`, if yes I want this number to be appended to an array:

I have tried both with a DataFrame, and also a ndarray woth numpy, but it does not work. This is what i am trying to do:

```
mail_addresses = pd.DataFrame(customers_df.iloc[:,0].values)
mail_addresses = mail_addresses.dropna(axis = 0, how= 'all')
mail_addresses_toArray = mail_addresses.values

for i in mail_addresses:
dates =[]
if any(i.isdigit()) == True:
    dates.append(i)
    print(dates)
```

I think my problem is that I don't know how I can convert all the elements in this array to string so that the method `isdigit()` would work and iterate through all the elements inside (825 mail addresses).

When running the code above this is the error i get:

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.int64' object has no attribute 'isdigit'
```

Meanwhile, if i try with the numpy array (mail_addresses_toArray) this is the error:

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'isdigit'
```

Comment: It's hard to know what's going wrong with `mail_addresses` without some more information. Can you please either post the code you used to create `customers_df`, or the output from `print(mail_addresses)`? If the output is very long, just post a sample of it

Comment: This is how i create mail_addresses:                                
 mail_addresses = customers_df.iloc[:,0].values  for privacy reason i cannot post the content of this file.

Comment: Just post a version with a few made up emails. Whatever is going wrong with `mail_addresses`, it's in the part of the code you haven't posted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) if each mail contains only one `number` or [`findall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) if there is possible multiple ones:

```
customers_df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['roberto123@example.com','foo123@foo.com',
                                  'bar@bar.com','23re55@re.com'],
                   'B':[4,5,4,5],
                   'C':[7,8,9,4]})

print (customers_df)
                        A  B  C
0  roberto123@example.com  4  7
1          foo123@foo.com  5  8
2             bar@bar.com  4  9
3           23re55@re.com  5  4

L = customers_df.iloc[:,0].str.extract('(\d+)', expand=False).dropna().astype(int).tolist()
print (L)
[123, 123, 23]

L = np.concatenate(customers_df.iloc[:,0].str.findall('(\d+)')).astype(int).tolist()
print (L)
[123, 123, 23, 55]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['abc123@gmail.com', 'bcdef@hotmail.com',
                         'sdafasf43@abc.com', None]})

s = df['A'].dropna()

t = s.map(lambda x: ''.join([i for i in x if i.isdigit()]).strip())
res = t.loc[t != ''].map(int).tolist()

# [123, 43]
```

Comment: Is it necessary to have a dictionary?

Comment: No, this is just an easy way. I assume you *already* have a dataframe to work with, as in your question. The solution will still work with your dataframe.

Comment: I have a dataframe, but I convert it to a ndarray using .as_matrix()

Comment: @roberto.sannazzaro, there's not reason to do that, if you want a `list` at the end. I'm working with what you have in your question. If you have a specific requirement, please provide a [mcve].

Comment: and i noticed that using your code returns me the error "'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'map'" do you think I should convert it into numpy array?

Comment: No. *Have you copied and pasted my code exactly?* I don't think you have.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168731/discussion-between-roberto-sannazzaro-and-jpp).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like:

a) you need to fix how you're creating `mail_addresses`. Somehow, it's full of `numpy.int64` objects instead of strings containing email addresses, like you expect.

b) once you have that sorted, you need to use the `.isdigit` method on the individual characters of each email address. Currently, you're calling it on a whole email address at a time. Here's an example of what I mean:

```
import numpy

emails = numpy.array([
    'foo123@foo.com',
    'bar@bar.com',
    '2re23@re.com',
])

digits = []

for email in emails:
    # first we loop over each email in the array
    for c in email:
        # then we loop over each character `c` in an email
        if c.isdigit():
            digits.append(int(c))

print(digits)
```

output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3]
```

If you want the whole numbers instead of just the digits, you can use a regex:

```
import numpy
import re

numRe = re.compile('\d+')

emails = numpy.array([
    'foo123@foo.com',
    'bar@bar.com',
    '2re23@re.com',
])

digits = [int(num) for email in emails for num in numRe.findall(email)]

print(digits)
```

output:

```
[123, 2, 23]
```